Request with proxy can't reach FastAPI webserver
I want to test my HTTP downloaders in GitLab CI/CD. So I chose FastAPI as the web server to which downloaders will be tested.
Currently, I am trying to make it work locally, but the request always fails with the 503 status code when I am using proxies (that I must use for testing). Without proxies I get 200 status code.
Here is my docker-compose.yml to set up FastAPI web server:
services:
  fastapi:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    networks:
      - test-network

networks:
  test-network:
    driver: bridge

Here is my Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.12-slim

WORKDIR /app

COPY main.py /app

RUN pip install fastapi uvicorn

CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]

Here is the FastAPI main.py:
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

app = FastAPI()

# Allow all origins, methods, and headers
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

@app.get("/test")
async def read_test():
    return {"message": "Hello, World!"}

And lastly, the test sample that fails while using proxies and succeeds while NOT using proxies test_simple.py:
import aiohttp
import asyncio
from aiohttp import BasicAuth


proxy_host: str = "HOST"
proxy_pass: str = "PASS"
proxy_port: int = 60000
proxy_user: str = "USER"

async def simple_test():
    proxy_url = f"http://{proxy_host}:{proxy_port}"
    proxy_auth = BasicAuth(proxy_user, proxy_pass)

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get('http://localhost:8000/test', proxy=proxy_url, proxy_auth=proxy_auth) as response:
            print(f"Status: {response.status}")
            print(f"Content: {await response.text()}")

asyncio.run(simple_test())

I tried making a request with curl to google.com with proxy and it was successful, so the proxies themselves are not the issue.
I guess the issue is that I need to make extra configurations within FastAPI that I don't know.
Note, that I don't want to put my testing code in docker-compose since many more downloaders will be tested and I want to have each as a separate CI/CD job, and in ideal result, docker-compose would spin up the FastAPI web server and my downloaders would be tested against it locally or in Gitlab CI/CD as separate pytest commands.

You talk a lot about this proxy, but never describe what proxy you're using, how it's configured, or how you're running it.

You can see the usage of proxy in the test_simple.py, it is a proxy_url that is used in the request. While it is applied the request keep failing (although I can make simple curl request while using the same proxy to external website and it works).

That's not what I asked for. If the requests work without the proxy, the issue is in the proxy. Hence, we need to know how it's set up and used to be able to help you.

It is a proxy from a proxy provider that is used in the request so I would not use my actual IP when making a request. It is used in the downloader, in this case, AIOHTTP, to be applied to the request. I think it does not work because I am trying to access localhost with proxy and the FastAPI believes it is from a different network and can't handle it. If the issue is with the proxy I would not be able to make requests to external websites with it successfully. Did I answer the question about the proxy?
